# Sending firebase push notification using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notification using firebase cloud messaging.
I have successfully stored access token in shared preference.

I am using Volley to send request to server but it(Volley) shows  **com.android.volley.Server error** after sending the request.

**Note: I am just sending firebase push notification on same device since the access token passed in body of request is of same(current) user**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String token= Helper.getAccessToken(this);
    if(token!=null){
       sendRequest();
    }

}

private void sendRequest() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    String url= "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Here ServerError shows
        }
    })
    {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            String accessToken = Helper.getAccessToken(MainActivity.this);
            params.put("to",accessToken);
            params.put("title", "This is string message");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String,String> header = new HashMap<>();
            header.put(""Authorization,"key=" + "Here is my server key");
            header.put("Content-Type","application/json");
            return header;
        }
    }
            ;

            requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems a little bit overkill just to make a simple POST operation. I think it would be better to use something like OkHTTP to carry out this operation. It should be a very straightforward POST operation

```
private void sendRequestByOk() {
    final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonData.put("body","Hi!! This is the message from device");
                    jsonData.put("title","dummy title");
                    json.put("notification",jsonData);
                    json.put("to",Helper.getAccessToken(MainActivity.this));

                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON,json.toString());
                    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                            .header(AUTHORIZATION_KEY,AUTH_VALUE)
                            .url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
                            .post(body)
                            .build();

                    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String finalResponse = response.body().string();
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, finalResponse,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return  null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: from where we get the auhorization key and auth value?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in below code:-

```
   @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
        String accessToken = Helper.getAccessToken(MainActivity.this);
        params.put("to",accessToken);
   //change this
        params.put("notification", "This is string message");
        return params;
    }
```

Comment: what error? and are sure that you have the device token for push notification.

Comment: com.android.volley.ServerError,
Yes I have the access token for push notification.

Comment: remove the get params method and try to send the parameters using jsonObject.